# How to convert buttons to a text box and button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am in the process of learning Javascript and found a guide for a text based game. Currently I have a game that you are supposed to find a cat in a 10x10 area. I use 4 buttons (North, South, East, West) and was wondering if it is possible to convert this into a text-box (user typing in North and they will move up one space north) then click a button to submit the command. I also am not sure how to connect the textbox, button, and Javascript but I tried to do it with what I could find online.

HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Text Based Game </title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Find The Cat!</h1>
    <p> Can you find the cat somewhere in this 10x10 world?</p>

<p><img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://www.noonco.com/rc/java_art/picture_doorway.jpg" width="200" height="150">
</p>
    <p> You can type in any of these words: <br>
    north, east, south, west, hint, help</p>



    <div id="hint"></div>
    <div id="help"></div>
    <div id='none'></div>

<input id="choice" type="text"> 
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="processInput" value="submit command">


<!--  <ul>  
<p>
<button onclick="myFunction01()">North</button> <br>
<button onclick="myFunction02()">West</button> <br>
<button onclick="myFunction03()">East</button><br>
<button onclick="myFunction04()">South</button>
    </p>
</ul>-->
<p id="demo"></p>
<script src="TextGame.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    var north=0;
var south=0;
var west=0;
var east=0;
var position = "Central Room";
var worldsize=10;

function processInput() {
    var command = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    if (command == "north") {

        myFunction01();
    }
    else if (command == "south") {

        myFunction04();
    }
    else if (command == "west") {

        myFunction02();
    }
    else if (command == "east") {

        myFunction03();
    }
    else if (command == "hint"){

        myfunction
    }
}

function myFunction01() {
if (north > worldsize){
return;
}
if (south < 1) {
        north = north + 1;
}else {
        south = south - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction02() {
if (west > worldsize){
return;
}
if (east < 1) {
        west = west + 1;
}else{
        east = east - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction03() {

if (east > worldsize){
return;
}
if (west < 1) {
        east = east + 1;
}else{
        west = west - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction04() {
if (south > worldsize){
return;
}
if (north > 0) {
        north = north - 1;
}else{
south = south + 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myposition() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (north == 7 && east == 4){
position = "Cat Freak Out!";
image.src = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/32/ba/19/32ba192e9eb99068a91fd2e8a1e21189.jpg";
}

else{
position = "lost";
image.src = "http://www.noonco.com/rc/java_art/picture_field.jpg";
}
}
```

Comment: `myFunction02` :o *PLEASE* give your functions suitable names. Future you will thank past you one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an `id` to the text field, that will uniquely identify it. This way, you can get it's value and then call a function depending on what the input is:

```
<input type="text" id="direction" />

<!-- The onclick calls the javascript function given to it -->
<button onclick="checkDirection();">Walk</button>
```

The `checkDirection()`-function should look somewhat like this:

```
function checkDirection() {
    // select the input field with the id "direction"
    directionField = document.getElementById("direction");

    // get it's value
    direction = directionField.value;

    // check which value was entered

    // the toLowerCase()-function transforms the string to lower case 
    // so that the check isn't case sensitive
    switch (direction.toLowerCase()) {
        case "north":
            /* do something to walk north */
            break;
        case "south":
            /* do something to walk south */
            break;
        case "east":
            /* do something to walk east */
            break;
        case "west":
            /* do something to walk west */
            break;
        default:
            /* get's executed if input doesn't match any of the above */
            alert("Please enter a valid direction");
    }
}
```

Feel free to ask anything.

Comment: Hello Stunt,
Thanks for the help! Though I changed my JS to the way Thomas James suggested in his comment as I understand that better than I do switch statements atm. Currently the button still isn't completely working and I'm not very sure why, I updated the code to the new code Thomas helped me with, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I would be happy to help you. Also, I can explain switch statements a bit more if you wish.

Comment: When I type in a command like north, east, etc. and click the button nothing happens. I'm not really sure as to why

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first, there are some syntax errors in your TextGame.js file that causes the entire file to not load properly. Remove this part first in your code which is causing the syntax error:

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener(onclick, choices);

function choices {
var choice = ['north', 'west', 'south', 'east', 'North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Hint', 'hint',
             'Help', 'help'];

var northExists = choice.indexOf('north', 'North') > -1;
if (northExists){
    document.getElementById(myFunction01);
}

var southExists = choice.indexOf('south', 'South') > -1;
else if (southExists){
    document.getElementById(myFunction04);
}

var westExists = choice.indexOf('West', 'west') > -1;
else if (westExists){
    document.getElementById(myFunction02);
}

var eastExists = choice.indexOf('East', 'east') > -1;
else if (eastExists){
    document.getElementById(myFunction03);
}

var helpExists = choice.indexOf('Help', 'help') > -1;
else if (helpExists){
    document.getElementById("help").innerHTML = "You must move around to find the cat somewhere in the world.";
} 

var hintExists = choice.indexOf('Hint', 'hint') > -1;
else if (hintExists){
    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML = "The cat is somewhere on the map.";
}

var none = choice.indexOf('north', 'west', 'south', 'east', 'North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'Hint', 'hint','Help', 'help') < -1;
else if (none){
    document.getElementById("none").innerHTML = "Command invalid! Type in a valid command!";
}
}
```

Next, You have to add an onclick event to the button, and then call the appropriate function depending on what the user entered in the text box.

First, add the onclick event which tells JavaScript which function to call when the button is clicked:

```
<input id="submit" type="button" onclick="processInput" value="submit command">
```

Then, in the `processInput()` function, get the value entered into the textbox, and then call the appropriate function to perform.

```
function processInput() {
    var command = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    if (command == "north") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction01();
    }
    else if (command == "south") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction04();
    }
    else if (command == "west") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction02();
    }
    else if (command == "east") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction03();
    }
}
```

Here is the entire updated TextGame.js:

```
var north=0;
var south=0;
var west=0;
var east=0;
var position = "Central Room";
var worldsize=10;

function processInput() {
    var command = document.getElementById("choice").value;
    if (command == "north") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction01();
    }
    else if (command == "south") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction04();
    }
    else if (command == "west") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction02();
    }
    else if (command == "east") {
        // call the appropriate function
        myFunction03();
    }
}

function myFunction01() {
if (north > worldsize){
return;
}
if (south < 1) {
        north = north + 1;
}else {
        south = south - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction02() {
if (west > worldsize){
return;
}
if (east < 1) {
        west = west + 1;
}else{
        east = east - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction03() {

if (east > worldsize){
return;
}
if (west < 1) {
        east = east + 1;
}else{
        west = west - 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myFunction04() {
if (south > worldsize){
return;
}
if (north > 0) {
        north = north - 1;
}else{
south = south + 1;
}
myposition();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "North: " + north +"   South: " + south+"   East: " + east + "   West: " + west + "<br>" + "Location: " + position;
}

function myposition() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (north == 7 && east == 4){
position = "Cat Freak Out!";
image.src = "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/32/ba/19/32ba192e9eb99068a91fd2e8a1e21189.jpg";
}

else{
position = "lost";
image.src = "http://www.noonco.com/rc/java_art/picture_field.jpg";
}
}
```

Comment: Hello Thomas! 
First of all thanks for the help! I changed the Javascript section and added the onclick command to the button but it still does not work. I am thinking that maybe I messed up something on the HTML part? Maybe I need to change something with the textbox? But I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value to a function:

```
<p>Click the button submit the command.</p>
<input id="command" type="text" value="North">
<button onclick="performCommand(document.getElementById('command').value)">Submit</button>

<script>
function performCommand(command)
{
  alert(command);
}
</script>
```